# Python - extending and filling list with zeros to match another list

Tags: python, arrays, list, padding

I have a list `a` with a few elements. I have another list `b` with more elements. I need to extend `a` to match `b` in size, using zeros to fill. In the new list that will come out, the original `a` sits in a position determined by `b`, as explained by example in the following.
Small example of my situation:

```
a = [3, 4, 5]

b = [1.2, 2.5, 3.7, 4.3, 5.1, 6.3, 7.3, 8.9]
```

I need

```
[0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

The first non-zero element is in third position here, to match where `b` becomes equal or greater than 3, and similarly the last non-zero element is in fifth position as a result of the comparison with `b`.

The final output is always `len(b)`; if there are too many zeros at the start to fit all of `a`, then elements from `a` are dropped.

Comment: So your input lists are sorted?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes

Comment: What happens if `a[pos] == b[pos]`, so there is a `3.0` in `b`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters then 'pos' will be the position of the first non zero element

Comment: And what happens if `b` has more than 3 elements outside the 'range' of `a`? Say `b = [0.1, 2.1, 3.0, 3.5, 4.1, 5.8, 6.6, 7]`? Or are you basically aligning your `a[0]` with a value in `b` only, then matching the length?

Comment: @MartijnPieters good point. In my case this will never happen, luckily

Comment: What would happen if there are more than 5 values in `b` that are smaller than `a[0]`? Would the output be longer than 8?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes. I just wrote 'b' of size 8 to make an example. The final list will always have the same size as 'b'

Comment: Right, so the output might need *truncating*, excluding elements from `a`.

Comment: @johnhenry, do not forget to validate the answer that solved your case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [3, 4, 5]
b = [1.2,2.5,3.7,4.3,5.1,6.3,7.3,8.9]

b.sort()  # Ensure they are sorted

start_zero_till = len(b) - len(a)
for i in range(len(b)):
    if a[0] < b[i]:
        start_zero_till = i
        break

revised_a = [0] * start_zero_till
revised_a.extend(a)
revised_a.extend([0] * (len(b) - len(revised_a)))

print(revised_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bisection to find the first position in `b` greater or equal to `a[0]`, with the [`bisect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

```
import bisect

def zero_pad(a, b):
    pos = bisect.bisect(b, a[0])
    remainder = len(b) - len(a) - pos
    return ([0] * pos + a + [0] * remainder)[:len(b)]
```

Bisection lets you find the point in O(logN) time.

An alternative is to use a generator function; loop over `b` and yield `0`s until an equal or larger value to `a[0]` is found, then yield `a` until exhausted and go back to zeros:

```
def zero_pad_gen(a, b, _sentinel=object()):
    a = iter(a)
    nexta = next(a, _sentinel)
    for bval in b:
        if nexta is _sentinel or bval < nexta:
            yield 0
        else:
            yield nexta
            nexta = next(a, _sentinel)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [1.2, 2.5, 3.7, 4.3, 5.1, 6.3, 7.3, 8.9]
>>> zero_pad(a, b)
[0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]
>>> list(zero_pad_gen(a, b))
[0, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

and for edge cases; `b` too short, dropping values from `a`:

```
>>> zero_pad(a, b[:-4])
[0, 0, 3, 4]
>>> list(zero_pad_gen(a, b[:-4]))
[0, 0, 3, 4]
```

First value of `b` matching:

```
>>> zero_pad([1, 2] + a, b)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]
>>> list(zero_pad_gen([1, 2] + a, b))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: @johnhenry: ah, yes, off by one error on my part, because `bisect_left` returns the insertion position *before*.

Comment: @johnhenry: All fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for i in b:
    if int(i) not in a:
        a.insert(b.index(i),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with list comprehensions

```
a = [3, 4, 5]
b = [1.2, 2.5, 3.7, 4.3, 5.1, 6.3, 7.3, 8.9]
num=[c for c,e in enumerate(b) if e>=a[0]][0]
c=[0 for e in range(num)]+a+[0 for e in range(len(b)-num-len(a))]
print(c)
```