# How to re-order and expand lists to have same size?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

I am trying to re-order and extend lists of dictionary values with the right position and fill them with zeros.

```py
myDict = {
    "col-1": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    "col-2": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'e']
}
```

The desired output should look like this:

```py
myDict = {
    "col-1": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    "col-2": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '0']  # '0' is zero
}
```

**Note** that values of lists are with order `'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'`. The maximum list length in `myDict.values()` is fixed to 7 and the minimum is 6. `myDict` can have more than two elements.

I tried to use [Python - extending and filling list with zeros to match another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46622130/python-extending-and-filling-list-with-zeros-to-match-another-list) but didn't know exactly how to make it work for my case.

Comment: what is the expected output for lists `['a', 'c', 'f']` and `['b', 'd']`?

Comment: `['a', 'c', 'f']` should be `['a', '0', 'c', '0', '0', 'f', '0']` and `['b', 'd']` should be `['0', 'b', '0', 'd', '0', '0', '0']`.

Comment: are resulting lists always expected to be of length 7?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The maximum length is 7.

Comment: And the values are only single characters in the range "a"..."g"?

Comment: yes, they are. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the maximum length is 7 and values are only single characters from "a" to "g"

```
myDict = {
    "col-1": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    "col-2": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] 
}

for key, value_list in myDict.items():
    new_value_list = [0 for i in range(7)]
    for value in value_list:
        new_value_list[ord(value) - 97] = value
    myDict[key] = new_value_list

print(myDict)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should cover the cases identified in the original post and the clarification comment.  The approach is, for each key of the dict, to iterate over the set of valid letters, outputting that letter (if it exists in the dict value), or '0' (if it doesn't).

```
myDict = {
    "col-1": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
    "col-2": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'e'],
    "col-3": ['a', 'c', 'f'],
    "col-4": ['b', 'd']
}

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
for key, value in myDict.items():
  myDict[key] = [(x if x in value else '0') for x in letters]
  print(f"{key}: {myDict[key]}")
```

prints:

```
col-1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
col-2: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', '0']
col-3: ['a', '0', 'c', '0', '0', 'f', '0']
col-4: ['0', 'b', '0', 'd', '0', '0', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that you could do this with a for-while loop:

```
for key in myDict.keys():
    myDict[key] = sorted(myDict[key])

    while len(myDict[key])<len(myDict["column1"]):
        myDict[key].append('0')
```

Comment: In OP's example, this would give `col_2` a value of `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'e', '0']`: so it would need another step to get the values in order.

Comment: I didnt see that part, edited to match OPs request